What is the expected number of rolls to get every number at least twice?

How many rolls will it take on average to see every value of a six
sided fair dice at least twice?

For seeing every value at least once, this question seem much more straight forward as you can think of each role as a geometric distribution for seeing a new value:
$$e = 1 + \frac{6}{5} + \frac{6}{4} + ...  \frac{6}{1}$$
I can't seem to think of how to extrapolate this question to seeing each value at least twice. When simulating this I get 24.0488.
My attempts first trying to define $X$:
I am thinking of letting $X_i$ be the number of flips until you see $i \in (1, 6)$ twice..but I can't seem to figure out how to solve for $E[X_1 + ... + X_6]$.
Let time X be the number of rolls to see all values at least twice. Let $x_i$ be the number of rolls to get $i$ twice after $i − 1$ rolls.

You don't want $E[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_6]$, because that's the expected number of throws needed to first see two 1s, then see two 2s, then see ..., and finally see two 6s, in that order (but possibly with other die results in-between).

What is a better way of thinking about it?

Let $E(a,b)$ be the expected number of throws needed when $a$ numbers have appeared $0$ times and $b$ numbers have appeared $1$ time each.  Then you can say
$$E(a,b) = 1 + \frac{a}{6}E(a-1,b+1) + \frac{b}{6}E[a,b-1] + \frac{6-a-b}{6}E[a,b]$$
with $E[0,0]=0$ as the end point and . You are looking for $E(6,0)$ at the start and can ignore cases where $a+b>6$. You can rearrange the recurrence to be
$$E(a,b) = \frac{6 + a\,E(a-1,b+1) + b\,E[a,b-1]}{a+b}.$$
Then it is just a calculation:
E   b   0           1           2           3           4           5       6
a                               
0       0            6           9          11          12.5        13.7    14.7
1       12          13.5        14.66666667 15.625      16.44       17.15   
2       16.5        17.27777778 17.95138889 18.54683333 19.08122222     
3       19.27777778 19.78298611 20.24129444 20.66125833         
4       21.28298611 21.64963278 21.99071648             
5       22.84963278 23.1338692                  
6       24.13386920     

and so the answer is about $24.1338692$, fairly close to your simulation.

Thank you -- can you maybe explain the probabilities and the recursions a bit more?

@user2330624: You throw once $(1+)$ and then: (a) you hit one of the $0$-so-far numbers with probability $\frac a6$ and turn it into a $1$-so-far number so $a \to a-1$ and $b \to b+1$; or (b) you hit one of the $1$-so-far numbers with probability $\frac b6$ and turn it into a $2$-or-more-so-far number so $b \to b-1$; or (c) you hit one of the $2$-or-more-so-far number with probability $\frac {6-a-b}6$ and nothing changes.

Note that the $14.7$ in the top row is your $e=\frac{6}{6} +\frac{6}{5} + \frac{6}{4} + \cdots+  \frac{6}{1}$ as it is the case where you need one more of each of the six numbers.
